# Why is the polynomial $F \in K[Z_0, \dots, Z_n]$ on $K^{n+1}$ not a well defined function on $\mathbb{P}^n$ in general?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Joe Harris' Algebraic Geometry and he says

"A polynomial $F \in K[Z_0, \dots, Z_n]$ on the vector space $K^{n+1}$ does not define a function on $\mathbb{P}^n$"

where $K$ is a algebraically closed field, $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the projective space over $K$.

I'm confused why the function $F$ is not well defined. Given $X \in \mathbb{P}^n$, a one dimensional subspace of $K^{n+1}$, isn't $F(X)$ simply the image of $F$ under $X$? Why would that not be well defined? Is it because we require the image to also be an element of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: Well, you want the image of a point (=a line) to be a point.

Comment: I guess the question is rather : what would be the target space ?

Comment: I think it was unclear to me that the image is also required to be in $\mathbb{P}^n$. I thought he was just taking about the restriction of $F$ to some $X \in \mathbb{P}^n$, with image still being any $D \subset K^{n+1}$

Comment: (1) He's trying to make an analogy with $\mathbb{A}^n$, where elements of  the associated ring $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ do define nice morphisms $\mathbb A^n \to k$ just by substituting the coordinates of a point for the $x_i$. (2) Try doing the same thing by "plugging in" points of $\mathbb P^n$ into a random polynomial from $K[y_0,\dots,y_n]$ to get a function $\mathbb P^n \to K$. (3) I don't know why you say "image of $F$ under $X$". That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Hoot (3) by "image of $F$ under $X$" i mean $\{F(x) \mid x \in X\}$

Comment: @Hoot (2) Let's take $K = \mathbb{C}$ and $F(x_1,x_2) = 3x_1 + 5x_1x_2^2$. Take the element of $\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by the image of $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (x_1, 0)$. This gives $\mathbb{C}$. Taking the image of $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (0, x_2)$ gives $0$. The function seems to be well defined at least from these examples.

Comment: I think the problem Harris is talking about is that the zero-space is not a subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$ unless the polynomial is homogeneous. I can't really see why the function would not be well-defined in the traditional sense (i.e. input giving multiple possible output)

Comment: Okay, so in your example $n=1$. What is the target of this function supposed to be? I don't know what "multiple possible output" means, really. To be clear, Harris wants a function $\mathbb P^n \to K$. What if I plugged in the line spanned by $(1,1)$? I get $\{3\lambda +\lambda^3:\lambda\in\mathbb C\}$. I agree that one can define a map $\mathbb P^n \to \{\text{power set of }\mathbb C\}$, but why?

Comment: It's a subset of $\mathbb C$. I'm telling you that this is not the kind of function he wants. [If you want precise statements, this is not a good book to be reading!]

Comment: @Hoot Yea I had a big misunderstanding / mind slip there (confused function to $K$ and function to $\mathscr{P}(K)$ as you pointed out). Though if we take a homogeneous function, say $F(x_1, x_2) = 3x_1 x_2 + 5x_1^2$, this doesn't give you a function $\mathbb{P}^n \to K$ either, right? This gives you $\{8 \lambda^2 : \lambda \in \mathbb{C}\}$? Just want to make sure that in either case it is not well defined in that sense, but it does make sense regardless to talk about its zero-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Well defined" is a term generally used for a function that may or may not be "well defined" on a quotient set; that is, on the set of equivalence classes of an underlying set modulo an equivalence relation.

For example, take $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z_2$. The latter is a quotient set of the former, where the equivalence relation is $a \equiv b$ if and only if $a-b$ is even. Then, the function $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R, \, n \mapsto (-1)^n$, gives a "well defined map" from $\mathbb Z_2 \to \mathbb R$. The condition to check, in all such cases, is that under the original map, on the original set, elements of the original set that are equivalent under the equivalence relation have the same image under the function.

In this regard, a polynomial $f \in K[Z_0, \dots, Z_n]$ defines a function from $K^{n+1}$ to $K$ in the usual way. $\mathbb P^n$ is a quotient set of $K^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, modulo multiplication of vectors by nonzero scalars.

The point in Harris's statement is that, given a polynomial $f$ of $n+1$ variables, the value of the corresponding polynomial function at $a_0,
\dots, a_n$ is *different* from the value of the same polynomial at $(ta_0, \dots, ta_n$) $(t\in K \setminus \{0\})$. This is true even for homogeneous polynomials. The only polynomials that do, in fact, work are the constants.